# The original value of unsortednums in my program is modified when I call a sorting function

Tags: python, sorting

Below is a program I am working on to compare different sorting algorithms. The first function there generates a random array of integers that I want to pass into the two sorting functions written so far. However, once I pass the random array of integers (stored as `unsortednums` in my main function) into the first sorting function, it modifies `unsortednums`.

I know this because when I try printing `unsortednums` after the first sorting function it prints out the sorted array. What I want to happen is for `unsortednums` to not be modified so I can pass it into multiple different sorting functions. Why are my sorting functions modifying `unsortednums` and how do I get them to stop?

```
import NumPy


def genrandomarray():
    """Generates and returns a random array of size 10 with values ranging from 0  to 9
    """
    nums = numpy.random.randint(0, 10, 10)
    return nums


def selectionsort(nums):
    passes = 0
    for i in range(len(nums) - 1):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(nums)):
            if nums[j] < nums[i]:
                temp = nums[j]
                nums[j] = nums[i]
                nums[i] = temp
                passes = passes + 1
    return nums, passes


def bubblesort(nums):
    passes = 0
    for i in range(len(nums) - 1):
        for j in range(0, len(nums) - 1):
            if nums[j] > nums[j + 1]:
                temp = nums[j]
                nums[j] = nums[j + 1]
                nums[j + 1] = temp
                passes = passes + 1

    return nums, passes


def main():
    unsortednums = genrandomarray()
    print(unsortednums)

    selection_nums, selection_sort_passes = selectionsort(unsortednums)
    print("Selection Sort")
    print(selection_nums)
    print(selection_sort_passes)

    bubble_nums, bubble_sort_passes = bubblesort(unsortednums)
    print("Bubble Sort")
    print(bubble_nums)
    print(bubble_sort_passes)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You need to make a copy of it and pass that to at least the first function so its results don't affect the second one. If you want to avoid that, it's possible to "seed" the random number generator so it will generate the same set of pseudorandom numbers twice in a row. (Although for such a small amount of numbers, that hardly seems worth it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You passed the list to the function.
The function sorted the list.
Now the list is sorted, as it should be.

unsortednums, selection_nums and bubble_nums are just different names for the same list. You passed it in, sorted it, and returned it, but the underlying list is the same for all of these.

To create a new list, which is what I believe you want, make these changes:

```
selection_nums, selection_sort_passes = selectionsort(list(unsortednums))

bubble_nums, bubble_sort_passes = bubblesort(list(unsortednums))
```

If the functions were supposed to do this for you (like the builtin function sorted), then this just masks that error. You need to change them to create a new list and return that.